# How do I allocate the output of a mex function without initializing it?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

The official examples do something the following:

```
//allocates memory for the output and initializes the mxn array to 0.
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, mxREAL); 

//gets pointer to the output
double *C = mxGetPr(plhs[0]); 

//function that writes to the output
some_function(C);
```

Is there a way of doing the above without initializing `plhs[0]` to 0? Initialization is not necessary since the array will get written into by `some_function`.

Comment: I don't see a `mxCreateUninitDoubleMatrix`, but are you sure this is actually a performance problem?  It probably just calls `mxCalloc` internally, which probably calls `calloc`, which is often just as fast as `malloc` since the OS keeps a pool of zero-initialized memory for this reason.  Basically, unless you've benchmarked the code and found a problem this sounds like premature optimization…

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure it is a performance problem, but I am worried about performance issues due to initialization since I am working with very large matrices (up to 17000x17000 double complex). Do you think it still won't be a problem in this case? Also, If you post the your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Try it and see, but it probably won't be too big of a hit, especially if you're not loading often.  If you're loading often you should probably look for a way to mmap the data anyways.  For something that large, I think most `calloc` implementations would just use `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, which should be extremely quick on the allocation side; it won't even clear the memory until you start using it, and at that point you'll be writing to it anyways so it won't have to be moved between the CPU and RAM any more than if it were uninitialized, and moving data is the slow part.

Comment: You can use these functions: [mxCreateUninitNumericArray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericarray.html) or [mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericmatrix.html)